# How to Create Common Header Footer and Sidebar in JSP?

Tags: jsp

I want to include common side-bar, header, footer and java application in JSP. Which one is the best approach?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Solution 1: JSP include**

Syntax for include a jsp file:

```
<%@ include file="relative url">
```

Example

```
<%@include file="page_name.jsp" %>
```

**Solution 2: Tiles insert**

Consider this JSP for a.jsp:

```
<%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/tiles.tld" prefix="tiles" %>
<html>
<body>
<%-- include header --%>
<tiles:insert page="/header.jsp" flush="true"/>
a's body...
<p>
<%-- include footer --%>
<tiles:insert page="/footer.jsp" flush="true"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Consider this JSP for b.jsp:

```
<%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/tiles.tld" prefix="tiles" %>
<html>
<body>
<%-- include header --%>
<tiles:insert page="/header.jsp" flush="true"/>
b's body...
<p>
<%-- include footer --%>
<tiles:insert page="/footer.jsp" flush="true"/>
</body>
</html>
```

**Solution 3: Splitting bodies**

Consider this a.jsp:

```
<%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/tiles.tld" prefix="tiles" %>
<html>
<body>
<%-- include header --%>
<tiles:insert page="/header.jsp" flush="true"/>
<%-- include body --%>
<tiles:insert page="aBody.jsp" flush="true"/>
<%-- include footer --%>
<tiles:insert page="/footer.jsp" flush="true"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Consider this b.jsp:

```
<%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/tiles.tld" prefix="tiles" %>
<html>
<body>
<%-- include header --%>
<tiles:insert page="/header.jsp" flush="true"/>
<%-- include body --%>
<tiles:insert page="bBody.jsp" flush="true"/>
<%-- include footer --%>
<tiles:insert page="/footer.jsp" flush="true"/>
</body>
</html>
```

**Solution 4: Templating tiles**
**Solution 5: Struts and Tiles**

for more you can visit : http://www.javaworld.com/article/2073902/java-web-development/ui-design-with-tiles-and-struts.html